# https://www.tokopedia.com/ Android webView load the link return Block Web

Tags: android, redirect, cookies, webview, user-agent

this link: https://www.tokopedia.com/ When our browser application opened, it was redirected to the following address: https://log.tokopedia.net/blocked-webview ;

Chrome can be opened normally. It is suspected that the server identified the corresponding browser through a cookie and redirected to the corresponding website. Please help, guys. Thank you very much

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.